# Cookie slide down div and remember on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am working on Notice bar which remembers when it has been closed and slides down if it has never been closed before.

However, if you do not close the Notice, and if you navigate through the pages of my website, it slides down each time. This can be irritating to the viewers.

How can I change the code so it slides down on the first view of the website, and then never again if you navigate other pages? I want it to slide down of first view, and then if you click a link it is just open. I tried making some changes to the last part, but could not figure it out.

[Live view](https://eldecosmetics.com/)

```js
var clearCookie = function() {
  var result = $.removeCookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification');
  if (result) {
    alert('Cookie removed, please reload.');
  } else {
    alert('Error: Cookie not deleted');
  }
}

var closeCookie = function() {
  $("#notice").slideUp(400, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  $('#fixed').animate({
    top: 0
  }, 400);
  $.cookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification', 'Notified', {
    expires: 7
  });
}

// Bind the buttons
$("#clearCookie").on("click", clearCookie);
$(".exit").on("click", closeCookie);

// Now display the cookie if we need to
if ($.cookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification') == null) {
  $('#notice').slideDown(1000);
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('navmenu, navmenu-mobile, #fixed').css({
      top: $('#notice').outerHeight()
    });
    if ($('#notice').outerHeight() == $('#fixed').css('top')) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 10);
}
```

Changes to not slide down:

```
var isUserSawNotify = $.cookie('userSawNotify') != null;
  if (!isUserSawNotify) {
    $.cookie('userSawNotify', 'Notified', {
        expires: 7
    });
  }  

// Now display the cookie if we need to
if ($.cookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification') == null) {
    $('#notice').slideDown(isUserSawNotify ? 0 : 1000);

 var timer = setInterval(function () {
     $('navmenu, navmenu-mobile, #fixed').css({
         top: $('#notice').outerHeight()
     });
     if ($('#notice').outerHeight() == $('#fixed').css('top')) {
         clearInterval(timer);
     }

 }, 10);
}
```

Comment: It works for me. When I close the `notice` part, go to somewhere else and back to your site, i'm not see the `notice` unless I delete the cookie..

Comment: I changed the post. What I want is if you do not close the notice, and you click a link, it should not slide down again, it should just be open.

Comment: So, when the page is loaded, set a cookie that the user already see the notice. Next time the user will get the page, check if the cookie exist and if so, don't slideToggle..

Comment: How do I do that? Im not very good at cookies

Answer (score 1):

I'm just explaining how to do the last part from my comment. (`when the page is loaded, set a cookie that the user already see the notice. Next time the user will get the page, check if the cookie exist and if so, don't slideToggle`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // this is the new part
  var isUserSawNotify = $.cookie('userSawNotify') != null;
  if (!isUserSawNotify) {
    $.cookie('userSawNotify', 'Notified', {
        expires: 7
    });
  }
  if ($.cookie('JSFiddleCookieNotification') == null) {
    // edit the specific line in your existing code
    // if user already saw the notify, just pass 0 to the duration so it will show the notify without the transition
    $('#notice').slideDown(isUserSawNotify ? 0 : 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. However the bar blinks and #fixed (the push down of the content) also blinks when the userSawNotify is saved as a Cookie. I inputed the changes in my post.

Comment: Ir blinks because it happening on the client. So the page ready (and visible to the user) and only **then** you display the bar. If you want to avoid the blink, do it on the server. (or hide the page until `$(window).load` which is not recommended at all)

Comment: Ah! I am using Shopify so I don't have access to a server for cookies I think?

Comment: If it is going to blink, it is better to have it slide down, so then it's kind of pointless.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Shopify but if you have an access to the server, you have access to the `cookies`

Comment: You can style the bar with `position: absolute`. The good thing is that it will not blink. The bad thing is that the menu will not be exactly in the center (because the bar will not take a place)

Comment: Still blinks when changing 'notice' to absolute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159847/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-vemund-eldegard).

Comment: If this answer your question, please accept it so it will help to other people.